# UTF-8 Problems while sending Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

I wrote a js script to post form data to my php backend. But the Textfield would receive it with a false encoding.

Here is my meta tag for this site:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Heres my textarea:

```
<textarea id="orderlistlieferanschrift" style="width:294px; height:80px; resize:none;"></textarea>
```

Here is my php script:

```
header('Content-typ: content="text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$postdata = $_POST["postData"];
error_log($postdata);
```

The Data is collected as follows:

```
var Lieferanschrift           = $("#orderlistlieferanschrift").val();
aOrderInformations[9]         = Lieferanschrift;
```

Here is my ajax request:

```
var postData = JSON.stringify(aOrderInformations);
if(!ajaxload2) {
    //alert(postData);
    ajaxload2 = true;   
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'share/content/helper/writeorderdata.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {postData:postData},
        success: function() {
                        ajaxload2 = false;
                        alert("erledigt");
        }
    });
}
```

In the server log the data where displayed as follows:

```
"Zentrale Oberursel\\nGablonzer Stra\xc3\x9fe 35\\n61440 Oberursel"
```

When I use the option data-Typ in jquery ajax an play with them an them the data won´t send.

Comment: You're actually getting the correct response from a text field. I use a similar thing in my contact form for my website. "header('Content-typ' could be type of course...

Comment: I´ve tested arround with these option but with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you must be sure every thing is in order....
1: Table DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
2: adding utf-8 in your html head section:

Try This after connecting to the MySQL Database...

Instead of using

```
header('Content-typ: content="text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

use the following

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: The error is the encoding in error_log for the json array: "Zentrale Oberursel\\nGablonzer Stra\xc3\x9fe 35\\n61440 Oberursel"

Comment: \xc3\x9f it must be a ß

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: doyou know utf8_encode(), Please find that, that looks the problem

Comment: could you put your string in utf8_encode(), like this  -  utf8_encode($postdata), as example...

Comment: I know this function I also implement this in php but the output looks then so: "Zentrale Oberursel\\nGablonzer Stra\xc3\x83\xc2\x9fe 35\\n61440 Oberursel"

Comment: function UTF8($str) {
    return (utf8_encode(utf8_decode($str)) == $str);
}

Comment: When I alert my postdata in javascript it were displayed correct.

Comment: I´ve found the failure. It was a layer 8 problem. I connected via putty terminal (ssh) to my webserver and xterm can not understand utf-8 without configuration. I wrote the data in the datatable with mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); and it worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding to

> AddDefaultCharset utf-8
>   to the httpd.conf (apache config file?)

Or maybe is it the mistyped

> header('Content-typ: content="text/html; charset=UTF-8');

to

> header('Content-type: content="text/html; charset=UTF-8');